# How can I get Google/OpenStreet Maps to use a non-mercator projection?

Tags: google-maps, openstreetmap

As we all know, the 3D-to-2D projection most commonly-used for drawing maps of the world is the Mercator projection. While it has its merits (e.g. for navigation by sea), it distorts area tremendously:

[image]

(the red discs are all of equal area on the actual face of the earth, but of differing sizes on the map). I want to avail myself of maps using, say, the 
[Peters-Gall projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gall%E2%80%93Peters_projection). Unlike in print, where you're stuck with whatever the print shop created - for online dynamically-drawn maps it should be a breeze to change the projection used.

So, how do I get Google Maps or OpenStreetMaps to display using Peters-Gall or other projections, instead of Mercator?

Comment: You can't in Google Maps, and you probably can't in OpenStreetMap, but either way you shouldn't ask for both in the same question. If you get one answer for Google Maps and the other answer for OpenStreetMap, how will you indicate the "correct" answer?

Comment: @AʟE.: If I were an optimist I'd expect an answer explaining how to do this on both sites; and if I were a pessimist I'd expect an answer saying I can't on both of them.